# django database functions cumulative count?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

is their a way to create cumulative count using/customizing django database functions. this built-in query gets the number of items for each year. what if we need the number of items before that year ?

```
items.values('year').annotate(nb=Count('id'))
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: year is annotated attribute using extract year from the original field posting date

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built-in in django. You can combine order_by, values and annotate to get what you want:

```
Item.objects.order_by('year').values('year').annotate(nb=Count('id'))
```

For the official docs, see: [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#values). If the sample doesn't work I'll need more information about the model to give you the correct call. Please provide the full model and, if required, some sample data.

Comment: I would be so impressed if this is true. any official sources ?

Comment: not working function call order doesn't change anything